# XSD validation with all required enumerations

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, xsd, xsd-validation

I have to validate below table using XSD.

Conditions to validate are..

1. Everytime there will always be these 9 unique records.
2. No Duplicates allowed.
3. Plan should be in the exact save order.

[image]

The XSD passes the above table even if we remove one record from the table or duplicate any record.
How can the above conditions be applied.
I have tried **use="required"** with enumeration but it was not working. I have gone through the lot of solution but no one fits my requirements.

```
<xs:element name="Plan" minOccurs="0">
             <xs:simpleType> 
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                 <xs:enumeration value="Actual DSP"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Actual OOR"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Budget DSP"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Budget OOR"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="FY Forecast"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Q1 Forecast"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Q2 Forecast"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Q3 Forecast"></xs:enumeration> 
                 <xs:enumeration value="Q4 Forecast"></xs:enumeration> 
               </xs:restriction> 
             </xs:simpleType> 
           </xs:element>
```

Comment: Lots of unanswered questions there, for me. Why use XML to represent this data structure? Why use XSD to validate it? What's the actual purpose of doing this?

Comment: @kimbert we have an excel which we have to validate using XSD. So we convert excel to XML first and then using XSD we validate it. Its a client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information that you shared. I suggest to use an xml schema that defines all the 9 plan options as childs of plan. Doing it this way you are able to meet all three requirements and keep the xml schema simple.
I assume that per plan option there is dedicated information, which you then can store as a child of the plan options element. Also keep in mind that xml elements cannot have spaces in the name.

I've made a simple example how you could set it up.
example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Plan">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Actual_DSP"/>
                <xs:element name="Actual_OOR"/>
                <xs:element name="Budget_DSP"/>
                <xs:element name="Budget_OOR"/>
                <xs:element name="FY_Forecast" type="ForecastType"/>
                <xs:element name="Q1_Forecast" type="ForecastType"/>
                <xs:element name="Q2_Forecast" type="ForecastType"/>
                <xs:element name="Q3_Forecast" type="ForecastType"/>
                <xs:element name="Q4_Forecast" type="ForecastType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ForecastType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Debit" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="Credit" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="Status" type="StatusType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="StatusType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Behind"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="OnTrack"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Ahead"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```